# Shell : choosing string between two strings using sed

Tags: linux, sed, grep

I have a log file in format like this :

```
pseudo=thierry33    pseudoConcat=thierry33
pseudo=i love you   pseudoConcat=i love you
```

I want to return all the strings which are between `pseudo` and `pseudoConcat`, my desired output is :

```
thierry33
i love you
```

How can I do this using sed or awk? I'm trying for a few days in vain.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -oP '(?<=pseudo=).*?(?= *pseudoConcat)' file
```

Output without trailing spaces:

```
thierry33
i love you
```

With bash:

```
while read -r line; do [[ $line =~ pseudo=(.*?[^\ ])\ *pseudoConcat ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; done < file
```

Answer (score 1):

With sed:

```
sed -r 's/pseudo=(.*[^ ]) +pseudoConcat.*/\1/'
```

Explanation:

- use GNU option -r to allow `+`, `()` without backslashes
- capture string after `pseudo=` with `()`
- string should end with a non-space `[^ ]`
- before spaces and pseudoConcat `+pseudoConcat`
- use 1st captured group `\1` as a replacement